# postgresql with timescaledb backup/restore and upgrade issue

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, timescaledb

My customer is using TimescaleDB 2.3.1 at PostgreSQL 11.20. We are trying to upgrade PostgreSQL and Timescaledb currently

I installed PostgreSQL 13.11 and and TimescaleDB 2.11.0

I backedup the database from PostgreSQL 11.20 and restored into PostgreSQL 13.11 like following procedure in documented TimescaleDB www site

The database that using TimescaleDB is about 400GB

```
pg_dump -Fc -f mytsdbdatabase.bck myTSDBdatabase        (from pg 11)
backup file size about 86GB

create database mytsdbdatabase;
\c mytsdbdatabase
create extension timescaledb;
SELECT timescaledb_pre_restore();
pg_restore -Fc -d mytsdbdatabase mytsdbdatabase.bck -p 5434            (to pg13)
```

After restore, when I checked new db it's about 136 GB but old one is about 400 GB. I was waiting some differences on size but it's too much
we also compared old and new dbs and we found that some data are missing
So what is my issue on backup and restore procedure?

Thanks

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe   Hello 
I have missing data, why this is normal ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. No, that's definitely not normal.There must have been error messages during the restore. Identify the first few (the rest are probably just caused by the first ones) and add them to the question.